# Transition EF Core 3.1 to storing string enum values, rather than ints

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'd like to know if there is an elegant solution to the problem of an existing database that stores enum values as ints, but wanting to transition to storing strings for new records, but leave the ints alone in old records. Naturally, we can make the column types from int to string, and "2" meaning "Ready" can still be stored in a string column..

Is there a technique that allows EF to parse either "2" or "Ready" to that `Status.Ready` in `enum Status { Ready = 2 }` ? I know that EF Core has an EnumStringConverter that can understand `"Ready" -> Status.Ready` but is there a way of extending or customizing it so that it tries to parse the db value both ways? ("Ready" as enum element name -> success, "2" as enum element name -> fail, "2" as enum element value -> success) Would we write a conversion process that e.g examined if all the characters in the db value were numeric and hence parse it as a value, else parse it as a name?

Or do people who switch from using ints to using strings also write a massive migration to UPDATE every value in every enum'd column so that all the existing "2" become "Ready" ?

Comment: But if you're transitioning from integers to strings you're already changing the column type, right? That means a rewrite of the entire existing table. If you can afford that, a one-time `UPDATE` of the existing data doesn't seem like much of an added effort. It would be different if you are now storing integer enum values in string columns, but that's peculiar. In my experience, supporting "piecemeal conversion" for compat purposes is almost always more trouble than it's worth and should be avoided unless wholesale conversion is just too expensive (i.e. too much downtime).

Comment: Can't you instead create another table associating the numeric value with the string representation?

Comment: @Magnetron I can, but then it's a case of "what does Status 2 mean again? Hang on.. `INNER JOIN Enums e ON e.Type = 'Status' and e.Value = mytable.Status WHERE e.Name = 'Ready'` .. for the sake of a few bytes I'm looking to clear the DB of magic numbers going forward. All our projects are string enum apart from this one project that was farmed out to subcontractors who didn't use EnumToStringConverter from the start...

Comment: @JeroenMostert a valid point, especially seeing as we have so many int enum columns that it will probably be a programmatic exercise to identify and change the column type. It's probably easier to parse Enums.cs with some simple find/replace to generate a bunch of UPDATE statements and do the conversion of the old values as part of a migrate - I'm still interested to know if there's a cheap way to make EF try to convert the "2" to "Ready", especially if I'm going to be adjusting the modelbuilder and making all the enums EnumToStringConverter, I thought maybe a custom one for phased transition

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), like the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.MyStatusColumn)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(),
            v => int.TryParse(v, out int val) ? 
                 (Status)val : 
                 (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), v)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my own practice, I store enum values as int in the database. For presentation purposes in the client side, I do the following trick.

In the entity class that has your enum property, Status, create another property that gets string value of that enum:

```
 public enum Status
 {
    None,
    Ready,
    InProcess,
    NotReady
 }

 public class Process
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public string GetStatus 
    {
        get
        {
            return Status.ToString();
        }
    }
 }
```

Here, if your Process object has 1 as value of the Status property, the GetStatus property just returns Ready string.

Hope, this answers to your question.